# ListView crashes. Not working app. Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, layout-inflater

I built a ListView and when i try to run the app it keep saying that it won't load. it needs to close. So i can't run it on the Android Studio virtual device.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;


    public class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView myListView;

    String [] items;

    String [] prices;
    String [] descriptions;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);


        Resources res = getResources();

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);


        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);


               prices = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
        descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);


        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items, prices,descriptions);


        myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);


    }
}
```

I created also a ItemAdapter class that inherits from BaseAdapter to inflate the layouts.

Item Adapter code

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //String array of the items
    String [] items;
    //reference to the other arrays
    String [] prices;
    String [] descriptions;

    //constructor for this class

    public ItemAdapter(Context c, String[] items, String[] prices, String [] descriptions){
    items =items;
    prices=prices;
    decriptions=descriptions

      mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    }




    @Override

    //how many items are in this list
    public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    //Get an item from the list
    public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items[i];
    }

    @Override
    //Get only the index of the item
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override


    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {



        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list,null);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);


        String name = items[i];
        String desc = descriptions[i];
        String cost = prices[i];

        //now we put the information on the textview

        nameTextView.setText(name);
        descriptionTextView.setText(desc);
        priceTextView.setText(cost);

        return v;

        //within that layout file there's going to be 3 TextViews to put in 3 strings

    }


}
```

I also make some changes in the String file under Resources

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Lists</string>
<string-array name="items">
    <item>Olives</item>
    <item>Tomato</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Prices">
    <item>$0.99</item>
    <item>$0.49</item>
    <item>$.89</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="descriptions">
    <item>Fresh Olives from Saranda</item>
    <item>Fresh tomatoes from Lushnja</item>
    <item>Fresh apples from Korça </item>
</string-array>
```

When i run the app the emulator keeps saying that the program has stopped.

What is wrong?

Comment: can you add the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: and please note, list views are old school. Try Recycler View. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your string array prices is written with capital letter, but you're accessing with small case letter.

```
<string-array name="Prices">
    <item>$0.99</item>
    <item>$0.49</item>
    <item>$.89</item>
</string-array>

 prices = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
```

try like this:

```
<string-array name="prices">
    <item>$0.99</item>
    <item>$0.49</item>
    <item>$.89</item>
</string-array>
```

**Edit**.

Something else you should pay attention is in your adapter:

```
 public ItemAdapter(Context c, String[] items, String[] prices, String [] descriptions){
    this.items =items;
     this.prices=prices;
     this.decriptions=descriptions

      mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
```

If you don't use `this` you won't pass the arrays from the activity, therefore your arrays will not be initialized. In the `getView()` method when you try to access them you'll get NPE.

Comment: perfect notice +1

Comment: Sorry my mistake while copying the code. it is with small letters. i don't have any mistake in typing or referencing. The idea is that when i run it don't work. keeps stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like that:

```
items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);


           prices = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
    descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);


    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items, prices,descriptions);
```

I think you might try this one here:

```
items[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
prices[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.prices);
descriptions[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);


    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items[], prices[], descriptions[]);
```

See how it will work.

Comment: @Inter_forever Try changing that in your ItemAdaptor constructor items[] =items[];
    prices[]=prices[];
    decriptions[]=descriptions[];